# [Pins latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm having trouble with CoreData a little bit, everything work fine separately  but when try to run them everything togather a got the error **[Pins latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

When I fetch the request in viewDidLoad I can't add any pen to the map .. but if I load the store with out fetching the request I can add pins to the map and they would get stored.

here is my TravalLocationsMap.swift

```
class TravelLocationsMap : UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    
    @IBOutlet var PinchGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults()
    var keysValues = [String : CLLocationDegrees]()
    let locationManger = CLLocationManager()
    var pinCoordinate = CGPoint()
    var operationQueue: [BlockOperation]!
    
    var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController<Pins>!

    
  fileprivate func setupFetchedResultsController() {
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Pins> = Pins.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)
         fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
       
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: AppDelegate.dataController.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
      fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
      

       do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("The fetch could not be performed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func PinchGesture(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let guestureView = PinchGesture.view else {
            return
        }
        guestureView.transform = guestureView.transform.scaledBy(x: PinchGesture.scale, y: PinchGesture.scale)
        PinchGesture.scale = 1
        
    }
    
    
    fileprivate func restoreUserDefaultsData() {
        switch (userDefaults.value(forKey: "lat") as? CLLocationDegrees,userDefaults.value(forKey: "long") as? CLLocationDegrees , userDefaults.value(forKey: "latDelta") as? CLLocationDegrees , userDefaults.value(forKey: "longDelta") as? CLLocationDegrees) {
        case let (latitude?, longitude?,latDelta?,longDelta?):
            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let regionCoordinate = setRegion(location: location, latDelta: latDelta, longDelta: longDelta)
            MapView.setRegion(regionCoordinate, animated: true)
            break
        default:
            print("Something Went Wrong Brother!")
            break
        }
    }
    fileprivate func populatePinsOnTheMap(){
        guard let pins = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else {
                   return
               }
        for pin in pins {
                  let Annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                  Annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pin.latitude, longitude: pin.longitude)
                  self.MapView.addAnnotation(Annotation)
              }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MapView.delegate = self
        setupFetchedResultsController()
        restoreUserDefaultsData()
        populatePinsOnTheMap()
        
          }
    
    
    
  
    
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
       // fetchedResultsController = nil
    }
    
    
    func setupRecognizers() {
        let longTapRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleLongPress(recognizer:)))
         view.addGestureRecognizer(longTapRecognizer)
         
        
    }

    @objc func handleLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            
            pinCoordinate = recognizer.location(in: MapView)
            let coordinate = MapView.convert(pinCoordinate, toCoordinateFrom: MapView)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            addPins(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
            recognizer.state = .ended
        }
    }
    
    func addPins(latitude:CLLocationDegrees,longitude:CLLocationDegrees){
        let pin = Pins(context: AppDelegate.dataController.viewContext)
        print("This is Pin instance \(pin)")
       pin.latitude = latitude
       pin.longitude = longitude
       pin.creationDate = Date()
        print("This is pin after set the values \(pin)")
        try? AppDelegate.dataController.viewContext.save()
       
    }
 

    
    func setRegion(location : CLLocationCoordinate2D, latDelta:CLLocationDegrees,longDelta:CLLocationDegrees) -> MKCoordinateRegion{
        
        let north = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude - latDelta * 0.5, longitude: location.longitude)
        let south = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude + latDelta * 0.5, longitude: location.longitude)
        let east = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude - longDelta * 0.5)
        let west = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude + longDelta * 0.5)
        
        let northToSouth = north.distance(from: south)
        let eastToWest = east.distance(from: west)
        
        return MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: northToSouth, longitudinalMeters: eastToWest)
        
    }
    
    
    
}

extension TravelLocationsMap : MKMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        keysValues = ["long" : MapView.centerCoordinate.longitude , "lat" : MapView.centerCoordinate.latitude , "latDelta" : MapView.region.span.latitudeDelta , "longDelta" : MapView.region.span.longitudeDelta]
        userDefaults.setValuesForKeys(keysValues)
        setupRecognizers()
        
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        
          let reuseId = "pin"
          var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

          if pinView == nil {
              pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
              pinView!.canShowCallout = true
              pinView!.pinTintColor = .red
              pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
          }
          else {
              pinView!.annotation = annotation
          }
          
          return pinView
      }
    

     
     func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
         operationQueue = [BlockOperation]()
     }
     
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            let operation = BlockOperation(block: { () -> Void in
            let pin = Pins()
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: pin.latitude, longitude: pin.longitude)
                                            self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)})
            operationQueue.append(operation)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
          for operation in operationQueue {
              operation.start()
          }
          operationQueue = nil
      }
      
    
    

    
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    static var dataController = DataController(modelName: "TravalLocationMap")
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        AppDelegate.dataController.load()
        
        
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        
       
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.


        
    }


}
```

Any suggestion why this is happing.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You set a pin as a Pins : {let pin = Pins(context...) }. May be a typo.

Comment: English is my second language, What I meant here is that pin is an instance of class Pins smth like that.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. When you fetch objects into pins variable, the type of returned data may not be of type [Pins].

Comment: I don't think that is the case because saving doesn't work even if I didn't fetch objects. In other words, if I removed `populatePinsOnTheMap()` From `viewDidLoad()` . The store will load, pins won't populate and saving pins won't work either.